# Locust not supporting `--exit-code-on-error` argument?

Tags: python, locust

Can someone help determining what I am doing wrong with having `--exit-code-on-error`?

```
python -m locust.main -f tt/tt_test.py -H http://thuis:8088/public --no-web --clients=3 --hatch-rate=1 --run-time=1m --csv=social_soak --exit-code-on-error=0
```

Getting below error:

```
Usage: locust [options] [LocustClass [LocustClass2 ... ]]

main.py: error: no such option: --exit-code-on-error
```

Clearly, `--exit-code-on-error` is supported as seen here: https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/610a87f433900d8baae51709c41e3b147a53bc97/locust/main.py#L286

If I take out this option, then the below command runs:

```
python -m locust.main -f tt/tt_test.py -H http://thuis:8088/public --no-web --clients=3 --hatch-rate=1 --run-time=1m --csv=social_soak
```

But I would really like to use the `--exit-code-on-error` option. Any idea how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you are using the latest version of locust (0.13.2 at the moment).

Probably the —exit-code-on-error feature had not yet made it into a release, or you didnt have the latest release.